# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Some bluetooth headpones connect, some not

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'd like to ask for your help. The situation is as follows:

Previously on Ubuntu 15 all bluetooth headphones used to work with some configuration files modifications described [here](http://erikdubois.be/installing-bose-quietcomfort-35-linux-mint-18/) and also on this forum. However with upgrade for 16.04 LTS the situation got much worse:

**Bose QC35** connects without problem and is automatically set as the default sound output device.

**Sony MDR-1000X** connects, can be selected among sound devices, but no sound comes from it with A2DP profile, selecting the HSP profile means the headphones disappear from the sound devices list.

**Sennheiser PXC 550** connects, but does not appear among the sound output devices no matter what.

I tried nearly everything found in the discussions, various operations with the Blueman, removing the devices, reinstalling the Blueman etc. I'm out of ideas and the only idea is probably to reinstall the OS, but I'm not sure that would help.

Can you help me, please? Is there some bluetooth cache or so to clean?

I wanted to post the content of these configuration files, but the forum would not allow me to submit the post marking it as spam :(

/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf

/etc/pulse/default.ps

/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11

Comment: `I wanted to post the content of these configuration files, but the forum would not allow me to submit the post marking it as spam :(`. Post the appropriate configuration files to https://paste.ubuntu.com and [edit] your question to include a link to it.

Comment: Bluetooth always has been weird on Ubuntu. Perhaps this question is also related since there is no info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/822208/bluetooth-headphones-problem-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the headset. I had this one time and sometimes it is a Bluetooth interference issue. My advice is to limit connections and if possible, use a wired connection.
But what works also is to disconnect the computer and the phone, turning off Bluetooth and finally pair the devices after turning on Bluetooth. If this doesn't works, I have no idea how to fix it. Sorry, I hope I helped you!

Have a nice day!